# Refresh and go to previous page on php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm showing an alert using JS on PHP and I want to refresh the page after certain time and go to the previous page. I tried using this code, but it gives me an error. Is this possible or is there any other way? Any help would really be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

```
<?php
$message = "New password did not match!";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
header('refresh: .5; url= '$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']'');
?>
```

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: Use `.` to concatenate in PHP

Comment: @PatrickQ so i changed it to "header('refresh: .5; url= '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']'');" but still had an error of "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '''' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ')'"

Comment: @ThomasVangelooven the error im having before i changed it is "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$_SERVER' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ')'" is there something wrong or should i use location instead of url?

Comment: I've solved the issue. needed to use url and the single quote should end on url. "header('refresh: .5; url ='.$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);".  thanks anyways sirs!

Comment: @Anthony.Jay those two `''` single quotes in the end are useless clutter.